# Multiple databases creation under same user

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know how to create different databases under the same user for different usage and different websites.

Just creating tables and manipulating them, will make all those tables in the same db even if they're not linked to each other, but I want to create my tables separately each on its own desired db.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name();
CREATE TABLE other_table();
CREATE TABLE new_tab();
```

All of those tables will be on the same base, what should I do then?

Comment: Create a second user and create other tables in that second user's schema. Unless you `GRANT` privileges to another user then no (non-DBA) user can see the tables belonging to another user so just create separate users for each application.

Comment: In Oracle, "user" and "schema" are pretty much the same thing and "database" always refers to the entire server instance, unlike in SQL Server and many others where "database" and "schema" are equivalent and user/login is independent of a database.